# About the language globalization

Tags: meteor

How to make the meteor application  support  multiple languages ? for example ：Chinese,English.

The first,I try to use the Handlebars.registerHelper and Session ,but I'm failed.

The test.js code :

```
    Handlebars.registerHelper('language',function(arg){
        var nalization = Session.get('nalization');
        console.log(nalization);
        var language = Session.get("language")[nalization];
        if (!language){
            console.log("nalization"+nalization+" is undefined");
            return "";
        }
        console.log(arg);
        return language[arg] ? language[arg] : "undefined";
    });

    Template.hello.created = function(){
        Session.set('nalization','cn');
    }

    Deps.autorun(function (c) {
        Session.set("language",{
            cn : {
                hello: "你好",
                language: "Language"
            },
            en : {
                hello: "Hello",
                language: "语言"
            }
        });
        c.stop();
    });
    Template.hello.events = {
        "click #language_cn":function(){
            Session.get("nalization") !== "cn" ? Session.set("nalization","cn") : 1=1;
        },
        "click #language_en":function(){
            Session.set("nalization","en");
            console.log();
        }

    }
```

The test.html code :

```
<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
<h1>{{#language "hello"}}{{/language}}</h1>
 <label>{{#language "language"}}{{/language}}</label>
  <button id="language_cn">中文</button>
  <button id="language_en">English</button>
</template>
```

changed the value 'nalization' in Seesion by click events，but the value is not change in registerHeloer .nothing happen on html.

Any idea about the language globalization ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the last paragraph on this page : https://github.com/raix/Meteor-handlebar-helpers

```
mrt add handlebar-helpers
```

There's the `getText` helper in the handlebars-helper package. You can see the source code at the end of this file : https://github.com/raix/Meteor-handlebar-helpers/blob/master/helpers.operators.js

About your code, I wouldn't use a session to store the language file/resources. The session should be used mainly to create reactive data. Also I don't really undersand why you use this `Deps.autorun`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I've done it by handlebar-helpers and non-synchronous local Collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
Language = new Meteor.Collection();

session.setDeafault("language","EN_US");

Deps.autorun(function(c){
  var languages = [
    {
      name:"EN_US",
      value:{
         username:"username",
         password:"password"
      }
    },
    {
      name:"ZH_CN",
      value:{
         username:"yonghu",
         password:"mima"
      }
    }
  ];
  if(Language.find({}).fetch().length)
      Language.remove({});
  for(index in languages){
    Language.insert(languages[index]);
  }
  c.stop();
});

Handlebars.helpers('language',function(){
  return Language.findOne({name:Session.get("language")}).value;
});

/**
    Change  language by click events
    for example:
    "click #chooseLanguage":function(){
          Session.set("language","ZH_CN");
    }

    in the html:
  <label>  {{language.username}}</label>
  <label>  {{language.password}}</label>

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the package http://messageformat.meteor.com/docs#features ?

```
$ mrt add messageformat
```

Its features are:

> Reactive (strings will update themselves when variables or language
>   changes) Supports MessageFormat selectformat (e.g. for gender), plural
>   and offset extensions Full translation Web UI, no need to redeploy
>   your app as new translations arrive Language data can be sent on
>   initial page load, or on demand when required (a reactive ready()
>   method is supplied for good UI).
>   Examples are here: http://messageformat.meteor.com/examples